# why won't this web request go thru for valid website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given the following why are the websites **Not** valid? I'm getting the follwoing error message.

```
try {
  HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://wrtire1.tru-m.com/");
  //2 websites that do this
  // http://wrtire1.tru-m.com/
  // http://acuraofaugusta.mobi/index.htm
  webReq.Method = "HEAD";     
  HttpWebResponse webRes = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

  if (webRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
    Label1.Text = true.ToString();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Label1.Text = "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ";
  // or I got this: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
}
```

**I received this error message**

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Um, how about an error message?? It would take five seconds to do `Label1.Text = e.Message`

Comment: @mellamokb - `e.ToString()` would be even better, as it will contain the stack trace as well.

Comment: Why catch an exception if you're just going to ignore it?  Funny thing about error messages, they tend to contain useful information.

Comment: @dtb : forgot to check the tags :)

Comment: In response to your edit, please post the entire output of `e.ToString()`.

Comment: I like how the error is *always* a 403 :-)

Comment: @Anna - that's it aside from directory info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen because the web server has had a look at your HTTP Request's User Agent and denied access, because it knows your application is not a legitimate web browser.

Many websites do this to cut down on traffic from bots and web-crawlers.

[Here's more information on the concept](http://abitsmart.com/2009/10/aspnet-detecting-bots-crawlers/)